# R - I cant concatenate a date with an hour

Tags: r

I have a date frame with a date column and another hour column:

[image: table of example values for date and time]

I want to concatenate the date with the time to be in the string format `"2016-12-25T08:38:00"`.

Initially I was trying this way:

```
datainicial=vpnsessions2[1,3]
View(datainicial)
horainicial=vpnsessions2[1,4]
View(horainicial)
dataehora=paste(datainicial,horainicial,sep="T")
```

But the result I get is: `17160T31080`

After searching I found that the time share is in seconds, and the date part is not sure, but I think in days.

I was able to resolve the time portion by doing the following:

```
td <- seconds_to_period(horainicial)
dataehorain=paste(datainicial,sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', td@hour, minute(td), second(td)),sep="T")
View(dataehorain)
```

But the result is still not satisfactory: `17160T08:38:00`

The time already appears fine but the date does not. I've tried several ways to try and put the date right, but I can not.

View image with code and values: https://snag.gy/koJca2.jpg

Comment: If you indent code by 4 spaces it will format properly.  Also for reproducibility please show the output of `dput(x)` for any input `x` that you use.

Comment: That way it doesn't work:                                                                      
> paste(as.character(vpnsessions2[1,3]), as.character(vpnsessions2[1,4]), sep="T")
[1] "17160T31080"

Comment: Maybe those values are epoch time? If so, convert them to their String versions and concatenate them?

Comment: Try this: `paste(format(vpnsessions2[,3], "%F"), format(vpnsessions2[,4], "%T"), sep="T")`.  Need to convert into the desired format, then paste together.